# How to get the next available UID from the file of users

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying print the next Available UID from the users list that I have in my file which I am achieving that by the searching the field and adding 1 to the END section. I also have written the script to run on that file. Now challenging part is, I have to consider ignoring the lines before a particular user, for example: "CS241-06" and check for the next available UID.

Here is my file name myrunfile1:

```
CS241-01:x:791:791:CS241-01:/home/CS241-01:/bin/bash
CS241-02:x:892:892:CS241-02:/home/CS241-02:/bin/korn
CS241-03:x:907:907:CS241-03:/home/CS241-03:/bin/bash
CS241-04:x:794:794:CS241-04:/home/CS241-04:/bin/bash
CS241-05:x:795:795:CS241-05:/home/CS241-05:/bin/bash
CS241-06:x:796:796:CS241-06:/home/CS241-06:/bin/korn
CS241-07:x:797:797:CS241-07:/home/CS241-07:/bin/bash
CS241-08:x:798:798:CS241-08:/home/CS241-08:/bin/bash
CS241-09:x:799:799:CS241-09:/home/CS241-09:/bin/korn
CS241-10:x:800:800:CS241-10:/home/CS241-10:/bin/bash
CS241-11:x:801:801:CS241-11:/home/CS241-11:/bin/korn
CS241-12:x:802:802:CS241-12:/home/CS241-12:/bin/bash
CS241-13:x:803:803:CS241-13:/home/CS241-13:/bin/bash
CS241-14:x:805:805:CS241-14:/home/CS241-14:/bin/korn
CS241-15:x:804:804:CS241-15:/home/CS241-15:/bin/bash
```

Here is my script file:

```
BEGIN {
 FS = ":" ; uID = 0; printf "\tNext Available UID is:\n"
}
{
      if ($1 == "CS241-06")
      {
        lineNumber = NR

          if ($3 > uID && NR >= lineNumber)
          {
               uID = $3
          }
     }
}
END{
printf "\t\t%d\n",uID+1
}
```

My run command:

```
awk -f scriptfile myfile
```

My expected output after ignoring lines before a particular user should be 806. I am not able to make this work. Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk solution:

```
awk -F: -v user=CS241-06 '$1 == user {p=1} p && uid < $3 {uid=$3} END {print ++uid}'
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F:                 # split on :
    -v user=CS241-06    # set variable
    '
       $1 == user {p=1}             # if column 1 matches user, set a variable
       p && uid < $3 { uid = $3}    # set another variable, only if p is set
       END {print ++uid}            # print next available uid
     '
```

**Output**

```
806
```

**Awk Script**

```
#!/bin/awk -f

$1 == user {p = 1}
p && uid < $3 {uid = $3}
END {print ++uid}
```

To run the script, do this:

```
awk -F: -v user=CS241-06 -f /tmp/test.awk /tmp/data
```

Note that in awk, the variables start with 0 value.

Comment: Thanks Rajput. Could you please update the solution how it would look in the script file. Sorry to ask but I am new to this. Thank you.

Comment: So..to my understanding..this solution in the script searches for the user(line) and ignores the previous lines before the user and prints the next available UID by scanning lines including and after the user line..is this right?

Comment: I have tested this and the output is always the + 1 of last line UID. I general if they are not sorted, how to handle this?

Comment: can you update the input and the output in the question...where the UID is not the +1 of the last line uid.. that will basically help me to understand the question better.

Comment: I made some edits to make sure to update uid only if it is less than $3. hope that helps...Let me know if that update does not solve your issue and I will work on another solution...

Comment: Works like a charm now!! sorry for the trouble. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: If it couldn't find the user you ask it to search for that'd tell you uid 1 is available even if it's already in use. Is that really what you're looking for?

Comment: @EdMorton Good question. If that is the case, the code in the END block be enhanced to see if uid is zero of not. If uid is zero, then print error in place of print ++uid

Comment: I think just printing the next available uid would be preferable but the OP would have to tell us. Idk how printing a uid as available when it might actually have been used before the target user appears in the file is useful anyway so this whole question is a bit of a mystery!